# Nonlinear systems for prey predator model

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I have a question with regards to finding the critical points and making sense of it in the context the prey-predator model. So I have a system given by the following:

$$x' = 10(1-\frac{x}{k})x-\frac{xy}{1+x}$$

$$y' = -y+\frac{10}{4}\frac{xy}{1+x}$$

Linearizing and setting the LHS equal to 0 results in:

$x = 0, y = 0, x = \frac{2}{3}, y = (1-\frac{x}{k})(1+x)$

Further solving, one eventually gets $ x = k $.

So the equilibrium points are (0,0), ($\frac{2}{3}$,0), (k,0) where k is some constant. In the model, it follows that $x(t)$ represents the prey population while $y(t)$ represents the predator population.

So I am asked for the equilibrium points, which I am assuming are the critical points obtained through linearizing. However, does it make sense for all of the points to be at $y = 0$? I am having a difficult time interpreting the result of a critical value and wanted to seek guidance to see if what I am doing is correct.

Any advice is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Replace $x$ by $\frac 23$ to get $y$ as a function of $k$. I also think that i $y$, you lost a factor $10$.

Comment: Ah right thank you, i get these critical points mixed up someone's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fixed points for this particular model are  as follows,

$(0,0),~(\frac{2}{3},\frac{150k - 100}{9k}),~(k,0)$

From this, you can easily interpret that when there are no predator or prey, the fixed point is $(0,0)$ (may be because of extinction). In addition, it can also be seen that there is a point, where the evolution of predator-prey gets constant and stays in an invariant set and attains the equilibrium (this corresponds to the $2^{nd}$ fixed point). Moreover, $3^{rd}$ fixed point depicts the unbounded growth of the prey (because of the absence of predator), which is again upper bounded by the constant $k$.